# Why is a Vue function not recognized when used in computed()?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

The following code (a Vue `method` is used in a string template when the component is mounted) works: :

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  methods: {
    perc: w => w / 100
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(`hello ${this.perc(20)}`)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

The one below = the above expanded to use `this.perc()` in a `computed` variable, fails with `TypeError: this.perc is not a function`

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  methods: {
    perc: w => w / 100
  },
  computed: {
    data: {
      y: `hello ${this.perc(20)}`
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.data)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

**Why isn't `this.perc()` available in a computed variable?**

Comment: You cannot reference an "under construction" object inside the object initializer block.

Comment: You accidentally confused the syntax of the `computed` section with th syntax of the `data` section. The computed should be structured like: `computed: { y() { return `hello ${this.perc(20)}`; }, }`. I'm voting to close the question as  "Simple typo"

Comment: @Ferrybig: no, the `data` in compute is not related to the Vue `data` structure. the naming is somehow unfortunate but it does not change the problem in my question. It is absolutely not a typo (just poor naming, and I forgot the parenthesis as this is a function - see the answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must be a function in [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html).

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  methods: {
    perc: (w) => w / 100
  },
  computed: {
    data () {
      return `hello ${this.perc(20)}`
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.data)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```